# What are the rules for importing with "as" in Python without using from

Tags: python, import, scipy

I was trying to import the following function in Python 2.7

```
import scipy.signal.savgol_filter as sgolay
```

I received the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named savgol_filter
```

savgol_filter is a function, not a module, so the error makes some sense. My question then is, is it not possible to import, without the use of the word "from" anything besides a module?

In other words, the following works:

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter as sgolay
```

But in general, does the following "sub_part" need to be a module?

```
import my_module.sub_part as some_name
```

I've seen lots of writing suggesting "sub_part" does not need to be a module. Is there something tricky going on with scipy that is making this not work?

Thanks,

Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you do `import thing`, `import thing.subthing`, `import thing.subthing.subsubthing`, etc., the far-right thing needs to be a module. Only the `from` form allows importing things that aren't modules. If you want a definitive statement of the forms of the import statement and what it allows, the [Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) explains it in great detail, but it's a pretty dense read.

Answer (score -2):

*import* is for importing modules. If you are not importing modules then you should see if its an object and create an instance like this:

```
import scipy as sp
sgolay = scipy.signal.savgol_filter
#Other stuff to do...
```